# go through subdirectories and make a copy of a file if it exists

Tags: for-loop, command, dos

I'm pretty sure the FOR command will handle this put I can't seem to get the syntax right (always sucked at programming).

I want to go through all the subdirectories under a specific parent directory and if the dog.txt file exists in that subdirectory, make a copy of it called cat.txt

This is the closest I got, but it put cat.txt in the parent directory:

```
for /r %f in (dog.txt) do copy %f cat.txt
```

Comment: Are you really running DOS instead of Windows? Are you a time traveler from the 80's?

Comment: @Barmar automation is thing for the future not from the past

Answer (score 1):

You're very close, you just need to use the path from the found file also. Should also protect against paths/files with spaces in them. Without a wildcard in the filename, you'll probably find the for loop will try to copy in each directory, whether there is a file there or not, to avoid this either add a wildcard or use if exist.

```
for /r %f in (dog.txt) do if exist "%f" copy "%f" "%~dpfcat.txt" /y
```

and a warning, if you put this in a bat file, you need to escape the % signs.

```
for /r %%f in (dog.txt) do if exist "%%f" copy "%%f" "%%~dpfcat.txt" /y
```

Comment: This will not work correctly unless the search term includes a wildcard of some kind - it is a limitation of this form of the `for` command.

Comment: @foxidrive, I already commented about wildcards. However, if the need is a specific filename, then wildcards won't work (may pick up extra files) and checking for the file in each directory with `if exist` is a better solution.

Comment: Yes, the `if exist` will filter the correct file.  My mistake.